# Should we introduce a "non-developer" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We clearly get more questions of merchants and other non-developers, but its not clear for everyone which could cause some questions to get closed.

To improve this situation, and offer a way to have an overview over such questions I think we need to introduce some tags.

What Systems do you think are suited for this?

Comment: The need for this may be mitigated as soon as we (Magento Small Business group + Piotr) get the new forums & Small Business portal online.

Answer (score 4):

Solutions which comes to my mind, and is only very simple.

mark questions with a "non-developer" and/or "merchant" tag.

Comment: Seems reasonable.

Comment: `backend` / `administration` might be different possibilities. `non-developer` implies that the default settings is for developers, which is not the only scope of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean closed as off-topic?

Do you have any examples where a question on magento.stackexchange.com has been closed because it's not developer-y enough? Because that shouldn't be happening.

In my humble opinion we shouldn't separate them. Developers are usually well placed to answer merchant-type questions. I guess it could improve searchability, e.g. you have a techy question and want to avoid the threads about admin panel usage; but personally I find a well-worded search phrase does the trick, and also there may be occasions when the answer you seek actually does lie there.

Comment: Developers are able to answer them, but they need to answer them in a different way then for other developers. And not every developer is good in explaining things to non devs. And I think its easier dor non devs to find suxh questions, because they will not be able to answer much else

Comment: Also, if you have a question about how to get a list of all products, the answer for a merchant would be different from an answer for a developer. The developer would get "Use the catalog/products model and get the collection", whereas the merchant would get "Visit Catalog > Manage Products"